# json to collection (list) in SpringBoot

Tags: json, list, spring-boot, collections

I'm trying to get a list of orders from another service(url) with `@GetMapping`.
I can't get the json objects and convert them to a list.I keep getting these and similar errors:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 
500 Server Error: [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: null at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonObject(JsonElement.java:91)
```

What should I do? please help me for how many days i can't find the right solution.

```
@Autowired
private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Value("${baseUrl}")
private String baseUrl;


public OrdersController(OrdersService ordersService, TradesService tradesService, RestTemplate restTemplate) {

    this.ordersService = ordersService;
    this.tradesService = tradesService;
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}




  @GetMapping  (value ="/restDeneme", produces="application/json")
  public List <Orders>  getOrders(){
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
      HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
      ResponseEntity<List<Orders>> response = restTemplate.exchange(
              baseUrl , HttpMethod.GET,entity,
              new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Orders>>() {});
              return response.getBody();

  }
```

Comment: Can you please show your code how you do that?

Comment: I added pictures,thank you.

Comment: Please post the code as text not as image

Comment: Hi, please also post the response from calling the GET on `baseUrl`, is it a valid json?

Comment: According to privacy issue I cannot share baseUrl but it is valid.

Comment: Any special reason for using Gson instead of Jackson? Additionally, @pleft was asking for the JSON that is returned when you call the `baseUrl` so that we can check if that is in fact a valid JSON (simply looking at the error it does not seem so).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to receive the data as a JSON object
for a JSON format like this;

```json
{
    "Kml": {
        "bicak": "AWAKEN YOUR SENSES",
        "jobsearch": "JOB SEARCH",
        "contact": "CONTACT",
        "video": "ENCHANTING BEACHSCAPES",
        "createprofile": "CREATE PROFILE"
    }
}
```

You can call it like this;

```
String loudScreaming = json.getJSONObject("Kml").getString("bicak");
```